# Debugging llvm with gdb but can't find source code

Tags: gdb, llvm

llvm has been compiled in debug mode.

```
➜  ~ file /usr/local/bin/llc
with debug_info, not stripped
```

In gdb,I use the `dir` command to specify the directory is useless.

```
➜  gdb -q llc                               
Reading symbols from llc...done.
pwndbg> set args memcpy.ll -o memcpy.s
pwndbg> directory ~/llvm-project/llvm/tools/llc
Source directories searched: /home/xxxx/llvm-project/llvm/tools/llc:$cdir:$cwd
pwndbg> b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1a2d7d8
pwndbg> r
pwndbg> info source
No current source file.
```

When I look at the debug information I want to change the build directory and find that all paths are in `~/llvm-project/llvm/lib/Support/`

```
➜  readelf  -p .debug_str /usr/local/bin/opt
String dump of section '.debug_str':
......
  [   25c]  /home/xxxx/llvm-project/llvm/lib/Support
......
```

I looked through the documentation and searched for other similar issues without finding a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Remap source file pathnames for the debug session.

If your source files are no longer located in the same location as when the program was built --- maybe the program was built on a different computer --- you need to tell the debugger how to find the sources at their local file path instead of the build system's file path.

```
(gdb) set pathname-substitutions /buildbot/path /my/path

(lldb) settings set target.source-map /buildbot/path /my/path
```

Specific to your question:
try:

```
(gdb) set pathname-substitutions /home/xxxx/llvm-project/llvm/lib/Support /home/xxxx/llvm-project/llvm/tools/llc
```

refer to https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html for more detail or reply to ask.